# csh error "set: No match."

Tags: shell, set, csh

So I am writing a calculator c shell script that reads numbers in from a file, and the shell returns the answer. For example, in the numbers text file, I would have:

```
1129 3100 +
```

and my csh file, once run, would return

```
Input from line 1 : 1129 3100 +
ARG1: 1129
ARG2: 3100
ARG3: +
4229
```

My problem is that when I get to the 28th line in the 28 line file, the output is:

```
Input from line 28 : 7 4 *=
set: No match.
```

According to my code, I this should return:

```
Input from line 28 : 7 4 *=
ARG1: 7
ARG2: 4
ARG3: *=
Invalid Input in line 28
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/csh
# Usage: Performs math operations

@ linenum=0

foreach line ( "`cat calc_input.txt`")
    @ linenum += 1
    echo "Input from line $linenum : $line"
    set argv = ( $line )
    set var1 = $1
    set var2 = $2
    set var3 = $3
    echo "ARG1: $var1"
    echo "ARG2: $var2"
    echo "ARG3: $var3"
    switch ($var3)
            case +:
                    @ ans = $var1 + $var2
                    echo $ans
            breaksw
            case -:
                    @ ans = $var1 - $var2
                    echo $ans
            breaksw
            case x:
                    @ ans = $var1 * $var2
                    echo $ans
            breaksw
            case /:
                    if ( $var2 == 0 ) then
                            echo "Error: Divide by Zero"
                            continue
                    endif
                    @ ans = $var1 / $var2
                    echo $ans
            breaksw
            case %:
                    @ ans = $var1 % $var2
                    echo $ans
            breaksw
            default:
                    echo "Invalid Input in line $linenum"
            breaksw
    endsw
end
```

and here is the file that I have to read for the numbers

```
1129 3100 +
-19 6 +
9 3 -
-7 6 -
9 3 /
4 8 /
35 6 /
12 3 %
13 3 %
4 19 %
11 9 x
4294967296 1024 x
-9 7 x
1024 0 /
14 63 <<
1234 5678 >>
1 2 3 4 +
1 +
3 -
7 x
12 /
91 %
7 ++
3 1 +=
6 2 -=
4 6 *
-11 7 *
7 4 *=
```

I only need to worry about +, -, x, /, and %. Anything that is not in the correct format I display the error message.

Thanks for your help!

And yes, this is a homework problem, I know that csh is a terrible, terrible thing and that most people don't use it. Tell my teacher that, not me.

Update: just tried moving the line that it has trouble with to a different line in the number file. It still has the issue, but it just occurs whenever the script encounters the:

```
7 4 *=
```

So it is not a problem with the placement in the text file. It is an issue with the expression.

Answer (score 0):

One syntax problem: You're missing one character in your default clause. Check your documentation, you should be able to figure it out.

With that out of the way, consider what `*` means to csh (wildcard). What's special about `*=`? Think of how you'd constrain csh to take it only as a character.

```
Input from line 27 : -11 7 *
ARG1: -11
ARG2: 7
ARG3: calc_input.txt
```

Figure out why `ARG3` is a file name.

```
Input from line 28 : 7 4 *=
set: No match.
```

That error message is pretty specific. Look it up.

"It's an issue with the expression." - It's about what csh does with `*`. Look into [globbing](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-13). Adding one line to your script to instruct csh to suspend globbing will get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is is the colon after default? I just added it and it still didn't work.

Comment: Yep, you got that. I've added another hint. You should try putting together some additional test cases of your own - what happens if you have `3 4 Y`, for instance? (It should hit your `default` clause... does it?)